# Modify camera2 policy - unable to get cameradevice

Tags: java, android-camera2

I'd like to get a reference to the cameraDevice when the camera is opened from GlobalActions.java in the Android framework. So to modify the running settings of the native camera. The GlobalActions is not calling openCamera so it's not likely to receive the state Callback

`    /**
     * {@link CameraDevice.StateCallback} is called when {@link CameraDevice} changes its state.
     */
      private CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

```
    @Override
    public void onOpened(CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
```

....`

How can this module register to the CameraDevice.StateCallback even if it hasn't called
`public void openCamera (String cameraId, 
                CameraDevice.StateCallback callback, 
                Handler handler)`
from a CameraManager instance ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [CameraManager.registerAvailabilityCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.html#registerAvailabilityCallback(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.AvailabilityCallback)) method whether you have opened a camera or not - it's meant to allow an application to know whether the camera is currently available to use or not.

Note that an unavailable camera doesn't always mean the camera is in use by another app - it could just be disconnected, for a hotplug camera (though this is relatively rare).

Comment: Thanks but I'm actually trying to force the flash when the camera is opened. the CameraManager.registerAvailabilityCallback will give me the status of the camera but not the object I need to force that flash. You can't set the torch when the camera is on with setTorchMode so this API can't be used (unless you heavily hack the framework). In fact, I would like to switch the flash in the torch mode when the camera is in picture preview, as it is done in video preview when you switch the torch on.

Comment: You can't control the camera when it is in use by another application, so if that's what you're trying to do, it's impossible.  Only the application that has the camera open can switch the torch mode on.